# Convert Hex code to Unicode in objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to convert this :

```
NSString *encodedString = @"Les Profs (Com&#xE9;die)"
```

into another NSSting in unicode :

```
NSString *decodedString = @"Les Profs (Comédie)"
```

I can't figure out how to do that easily...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: That's an odd way of coding a character.  Where did it come from?

Comment: That's what my API returns me... You'll find some more information here : http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-fr.htm

Comment: 'odd'? it's regular XML/HTML character encoding.

Comment: @MikeWeller That's why it should be decoded by a XML parser. If used outside XML/HTML, it's very odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your encoded string is containing html entities. You need to convert them to their unicode representation to get the required decoded string.

For conversion you can use following NSString extention
http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSString%2BHTML.h
http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/source/browse/trunk/Foundation/GTMNSString%2BHTML.m

Here's how u will decode the string then

```
decodedStr = [encodedStr gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML];
```

Answer (score 0):

CFStringTransform is the Core Foundation function that gives you what you need.