# Convert hexString to unicode string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I need a code, to convert @"043b" to @"л"

Here is what I tried

```
// get a hex string (@"0x043b")
NSString *hexString = [@"0x" stringByAppendingString:@"043b"];

// scan an unsined int from it (1083 as expected)
NSScanner* pScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:hexString];
unsigned int iValue;
[pScanner scanHexInt: &iValue];

// get a unichar from it (';')
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:iValue];
unichar character = [number unsignedCharValue];

// get a string (@";")
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", character];
```

but I get @";" instead of @"л"

I also tried

```
// get a char (';')
char character = [number charValue];

// get a string (@";")
NSString * result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", character];
```

Please, help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812034/convert-hex-code-to-unicode-in-objective-c

Comment: Once you have the int use this post to finish your code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775859/how-to-convert-a-unichar-value-to-an-nsstring-in-objective-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```
int value = 0;
sscanf([@"043b" cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], "%x", &value);

NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", value];
```

But the compiler is warning me on the last line, so the answer is not that clean

```
Format specifies type 'unichar' (aka 'unsigned short') but the argument has type 'int'
```

Tested both on the 32- and 64-bit processors

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
unsigned long hexBytes = 0x3b04;
NSString *theString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&hexBytes length:sizeof(hexBytes) encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
NSLog(theString, @"");
```

Important point: you have to reverse your bytes so it's 0x3b04 instead of 0x043b.

Comment: You may take a look at the solution I found. I does not require bytes reversing